# Create join table with no primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, primary-key, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables with a many to many relationship that I am using has_and_belongs_to_many to define the association.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bar
  ...
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foo
  ...
end
```

I also have the class defined to represent the join table

```
class BarFoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
  ...
end
```

When I run rake db:seed I get the following error:

```
Primary key is not allowed in a has_and_belongs_to_many join table (bar_foo)
```

If I edit the database and remove the primary key field (ID) from the bar_foo table and then rerun rake db:seed everything works as desired.

Given the above, what is the preferred means of creating join tables in rails with no primary key?

I also tried using "has_many :bars, :through => :foo" and vise versa but got an error message something like "undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass".

Answer (score 24):

Yes, primary key is not allowed for `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

You have 2 ways to solve this:

Remove the primary key on that table. In your migration class:

```
create_table :bar_foo, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :bar_id
  t.integer :foo_id
end
```

Apart from this, you will have to delete the file `bar_foo.rb` from `app/models` and also remove any fixture and test files that might have been generated. A good idea is to call the `script/destroy` (or `rails destroy`) to destroy the files and then regenerating the migration.

Or convert to `has_many :through`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :bar_foos
  has_many :bars, :through => :bar_foos
  ...
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :bar_foos
  has_many :foos, :through => :bar_foos
  ...
end

class BarFoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the model

```
class BarFoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
  ...
end
```

the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association will search for a table called `bar_foo` in your database what you need to do is generate a migration to create this table.

rails generate migration add_table_bar_foo_for_association

then you edit your migration and it should look like this

```
class AddTableBarFooForAssociation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :bar_foo, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :bar
        t.references :foo
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :bar_foo
  end
end
```

Now your association should work and also if you need the association to have extra attributes on the join you can use the `has_many :through` way and create a model associated to this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a HABTM association you shouldn't create a model for it - just a table `bars_foos` with `bar_id` and `foo_id` integer columns.

If you need the model in between (e.g. if you want to keep track of `created_at` or some other attributes of the relation) you can add additional model e.g. `Barred` and then you'd have:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :bars, :through => :barred
  ...
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :foos, :through => :barred
  ...
end

class Barred < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_many :foos
end
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for the response.  I'm relatively new to RoR so what is the preferred means of creating a table with no corresponding model files?  Would this just be done by generating a migration file and using create_table to define the table with the two attributes bar_id and foo_id?

Comment: Here's a nice answer how to do it: [Do I need to manually create a migration for a HABTM join table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564306/do-i-need-to-manually-create-a-migration-for-a-habtm-join-table)