# Does rails let you generate a HABTM migration from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Whenever I've had to do a **HABTM** in rails I've always found myself wondering if it's possible to generate the required migration from the command line.

I was hoping to save time by just doing something like this:

```
rails g migration tracks_podcasts tracks:references podcasts:references id:false
```

The above code doesn't work, and neither do several variations of it (with and without the id:false instruction)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to manually create a migration for a HABTM join table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564306/do-i-need-to-manually-create-a-migration-for-a-habtm-join-table)

Comment: Seems to be a better answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561330/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many-migration

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to the rails documentation, that should work, but you would want to replace 'references' with 'integer'. 'references' isn't a valid data type.  And get rid of the id:false entry.  The references and :id => false should be specified within the migration after generation.  You will basically generate a basic migration with all the fields you want, then open the migration and modify it to meet your specs.

```
Usage:
  rails generate migration NAME [field:type field:type] [options]

Options:
  -o, --orm=NAME  # Orm to be invoked
                  # Default: active_record

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Description:
    Create rails files for migration generator.
```

Comment: references is a valid value to use, t.references :foo translates into t.integer :foo_id. In fact you can create your own types as is seen with the devise model migrations and t.timestamps

Comment: I support Cluster's comment. 'references' is the way to go if you wanna express a foreign key relation. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/zealot128/ruby-habtm-generator is a nice option for this now.

Example:

```
rails g habtm user post
```

Comment: Please note naming convention as of rails 4 - not implemented in ruby-habtm-generator yet: 
If your tables share a common prefix, it will only appear once at the beginning. For example, the tables “catalog_categories” and “catalog_products” generate a join table name of “catalog_categories_products”.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many