# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models `restaurant` and `user` that I want to perform a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I have already gone into the model files and added the `has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurants` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

I assume at this point I should be able to do something like with Rails 3:

```
rails generate migration ....
```

but everything I have tried seems to fail. I'm sure this is something really simple I'm new to rails so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You need to add a separate join table with only a `restaurant_id` and `user_id` (no primary key), in **alphabetical order**.

First run your migrations, then edit the generated migration file.

**Rails 3**

```
rails g migration create_restaurants_users_table
```

**Rails 4**:

```
rails g migration create_restaurants_users
```

**Rails 5**

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableRestaurantUser restaurants users
```

From the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#writing-a-migration):

> There is also a generator which will produce join tables if JoinTable
>   is part of the name:

---

Your migration file (note the `:id => false`; it's what prevents the creation of a primary key):

**Rails 3**

```
class CreateRestaurantsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :restaurants_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :restaurant
        t.references :user
    end
    add_index :restaurants_users, [:restaurant_id, :user_id]
    add_index :restaurants_users, :user_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :restaurants_users
  end
end
```

**Rails 4**

```
class CreateRestaurantsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :restaurants_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :restaurant
      t.belongs_to :user
    end
  end
end
```

`t.belongs_to` will automatically create the necessary indices. `def change` will auto detect a forward or rollback migration, no need for up/down.

**Rails 5**

```
create_join_table :restaurants, :users do |t|
  t.index [:restaurant_id, :user_id]
end
```

Note: There is also an option for a custom table name that can be passed as a parameter to create_join_table called `table_name`. From the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table)

> By default, the name of the join table comes from the union of the
>   first two arguments provided to create_join_table, in alphabetical
>   order. To customize the name of the table, provide a :table_name
>   option:

Comment: thanks that solution worked perfectly for me. Made a simple mistake when using this method, I tried a rake db:migrate after the rails command and it didn't generate the table. Had to do a rake db:rollback then edit the file then do rake db:migrate but everything works now.

Comment: @Dex - Just out of curiosity, could you explain why you're using a second compound index, defined with reversed column order? I was under the impression that the column order didn't matter. I'm no DBA, just want to further my own understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @Jimbo You don't need it that way, it really depends on your queries. The indexes read left to right so the first one will be fastest if you are searching on `restaurant_id`. The second will help if you are searching on `user_id`. If you are searching on both, I would think the database would be smart enough to only need one. So I guess the second one doesn't really need to be compounded. This was more of just an example. This was a Rails question though, so posting in the DB section would yield a more complete answer.

Comment: The second index has some redundancy - as long as you are querying on both restaurant_id and user_id, their order in your SQL doesn't matter, and the first index will be used. It will also be used if you are only querying on restaurant_id. The second index only needs to be on :user_id, and would get used in cases where you are only querying on user_id (which the first index wouldn't help with due to the order of its keys).

Comment: Thanks for the solution-- I wanted to say there was one confusing point. When you reference the ":user" the rails systems seems to automatically reference the "user_id" field. I was a bit hung up on that for a bit.

Comment: @Corey Yes, there's a lot of built in stuff that relies on naming conventions in Rails

Comment: In rails 4 the migration must be `rails g migration create_restaurants_users` without _table_ at the end.

Comment: You could also use rails g migration CreateJoinTableRestaurantUser restaurant user. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-join-table

Comment: You also want to remove the index in the self.down call probably

Comment: What is the purpose of indexing the user_id alone? Why isn't this done for just the restaurant_id as well?

Comment: The first index (on both columns) most of the time should be unique.

Comment: Worth noting that `create_join_table` can be used at least in Rails >= 4.2

Answer (score 43):

The answers here are quite dated. As of Rails 4.0.2, your migrations make use of `create_join_table`.

To create the migration, run:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableRestaurantsUsers restaurant user
```

This will generate the following:

```
class CreateJoinTableRestaurantsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :restaurants, :users do |t|
      # t.index [:restaurant_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :restaurant_id]
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to index these columns, uncomment the respective lines and you're good to go!

Comment: I generally would uncomment one of the index lines and add `unique: true` to it. This will prevent duplicate relationships being created.

Answer (score 26):

When creating the join table, pay careful attention to the requirement that the two tables need to be listed in **alphabetical order** in the migration name/class. This can easily bite you if your model names are similar, e.g. "abc" and "abb". If you were to run

```
rails g migration create_abc_abb_table
```

Your relations will **not** work as expected. You must use

```
rails g migration create_abb_abc_table
```

instead.

Comment: Which comes first? foo or foo_bar?

Comment: Ran in a rails console: ["foo_bar", "foo", "foo bar"].sort # => ["foo", "foo bar", "foo_bar"]
Unix sort comes up the same.

Answer (score 6):

For HABTM relationships, you need to create a join table. There is only join table and that table should not have an id column. Try this migration.

```
def self.up
  create_table :restaurants_users, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :restaurant_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_table :restaurants_users
end
```

You must check [this relationship rails guide tutorials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: I don't think you need a model and I don't see anything in the link about needing a model for a HABTM relationship.

Comment: To speed up the generated queries, add indices to the id fields.