# Rails 4 has_and_belongs_to_many association, id: false still required on join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In some previous stackoverflow questions, for example:

[Rails 3 has_and_belongs_to_many migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561330/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many-migration)

It suggests setting the :id => false for the join table of this association.

Now in the rails guides (for 4 presumably), it doesn't mention doing this in their example.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Is this still a requirement? I've done it with and it seems to work ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in Rails 4 if you use the `rails g migration CreateJoinTableCustomerProduct customer product` it will create the join table with no primary key by default since this is the preferred style. You don't need a primary key in a join table like this.