# Rails 4 Setting A Relationship with HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two existing Models - Schools and Users.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :schools
```

My question is, how can I assign and user to a school? I can't quite figure out how to get it so that School.users returns any values.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is defined for an instance of school (a specific school), so `School.users` will never work.

Assuming you have the correct tables setup (you will have to manually create the migration for the join table, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561330/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many-migration)), it is actually pretty easy.

```
school = School.first
user = User.first

# add user to school
school.users << user

# or v.v.
user.schools << school
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user just to belong to one particular school (which makes most sense in case of students and teachers, staff etc) you need to change your associations to:

School

has_many :users

User

belongs_to :school

Then you also need to have a 
user_id:integer column in your school table.

Now you can query.

school = School.first

school.users

If you want a many to many relationship you need to create a schools_users table with school_id and user_id field.