# How to create a migration for a model1s_model2s has_and_belongs_to_many table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, how do I create the migration to create the join table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create_table :articles_tags, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :article, :tag
end
```

Taken from answer:
[Do I need to manually create a migration for a HABTM join table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564306/do-i-need-to-manually-create-a-migration-for-a-habtm-join-table#answer-564327)