# How to set up a typical users HABTM roles relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, relational-database, has-and-belongs-to-many, cancan

I'm quite new to this and I'm using cancan + devise for my user auth. However I'm not really sure what it means to set up a typical users HABTM roles relationship nor do I really understand what a HABTM relationship is.

Can anyone explain it really well or point me to a good tutorial or example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HABTM means has and belongs to many. You basically need a table as a middle man to track multiple id's (called a through table). When referenced as a typical users HABTM roles relationship, they really mean there would be a `User` model, `Role` model, users table, roles table, and a roles_users table. Don't forget to add the the HABTM -- roles_users -- table. A typical setup follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

You can then use the associations like normal saying `User.first.roles` and `Role.first.users`.

There are also a [couple](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) on your issues.

Comment: how do you create the users_roles table?

Comment: `rails g migration add_users_roles_table`

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon, edit the above with the following information: [gist](https://gist.github.com/1082098). Then run `rake db:migrate`. That should do it.

Comment: @recursive shouldn't it be `rails g migration add_roles_users_table` ? I thought Rails expects the 2 models to be in alphabetical order

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby on Rails Guides are a good starting point [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) also [this](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) tutorial is exactly what you want

Comment: I'm using the second tutorial, but it just says, 'set up a HABTM relationships' doesn't say how

Comment: http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/rails-has_and_belongs_to_many/ - simple tutorial on habtm

Comment: Most of the have a UsersHaveAndBelongToManyRoles migration, how do you generate that?

Comment: The docs are ridiculously vague on this...Ugh. Thanks for the tutorials.