# Ruby on Rails: associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm pretty new to ROR so I'm stuck at the moment with this problem.

I'm setting up an application with articles and templates.
I want to create templates with many articles, and the same articles can be assigned to several different templates.
So when you create a templates I want to assign articles to it. You will think directly use a has_many association but I don't think this grasps my problem.

I want to assign articles to multiple templates so I thought using a linking table of some sort would be at place here.

But I don't know how to do it in rails! Or what kind of solution I should look for.

Is there anybody who could advise me with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create linking model articles_template

```
rails generate model articles_template
```

with references to article and template

```
class CreateArticlesTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles_templates do |t|
      t.references :article
      t.references :template
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and then set the association in model articles_template

```
class ArticlesTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :template
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles_templates
  has_many :templates, :through => :articles_templates
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :articles_templates
  has_many :articles, :through => articles_templates
end
```

IMHO this is the best practice because you can add some extra functionality right into the linking model and table. (more about this [here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off))

Comment: This is also a very good solution to the question. In the end, it really depends on whether or not you need to have some state associated with the connection of the two models.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out stuff on [has_and_belongs_to_many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689540/how-to-set-up-a-typical-users-habtm-roles-relationship)

Essentially, go to the console and type

> $ rails g model article title:string body:text
>
> $ rails g model template name:string some_other_attributes:type etc etc
>
> $ rails g migration create_articles_templates

Then edit the create_articles_templates with:

```
class CreateArticlesTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :articles_templates, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :template_id, :article_id
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```