# Ruby on rails - Retrieve array of ids and using that array to query a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a model "`Events`" and each event contains an array of ids for "`Genre`" (a different model). When I create an event, I check a bunch of boxes and save the checked genres to the database. That is all working fine.

When I run my loop to display all events, the field `genre_ids` returns me an array with the id's for each selected genre that needs to be retrieved from the `genres` table.

I tried suggestions that I found but had no success yet.

Genre model:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :genres
end
```

Events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @event_all = Event.all
  end

 def get_genres(event_id)
   @event_genre = Event.find(event_id).genre_id
 end
 helper_method :get_genres

end

 -------
```

And finally the loop:

```
<div id="index-events-wrap">
   <% @event_all.each do |ea| %>
     <div class="item">
     <div class="event-image">
       image here
     </div>
    <ul>
      <li><%= ea.name %></li>
      <li><%= get_genres(ea.id)  %></li>
      <li><%= ea.venue_name %></li>
      <li><%= ea.venue_address %></li>
      <li><%= ea.venue_postcode %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
@event_all = Event.includes(:genres).all
```

It will make one more query (to avoid multiple instantiation of the Genre instances) and populate all the associations automatically. So in the view you can:

```
<li><%= ea.genres %></li>
```

By the way, you should have `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both classes, otherwise Rails won't understand it.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres # <- this one
end
```

If needed, add a migration for the join table, see [Do I need to manually create a migration for a HABTM join table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564306/do-i-need-to-manually-create-a-migration-for-a-habtm-join-table)

Comment: +1, i was about to answer the same thing. You should also avoid using `.all` (works fine in the beginning, but imagine that with a billion events...). Use `.limit`, or something like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/) / [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Comment: I see what you mean about the .all. That is temporary because as soon as i implement it a intended, it won't be .all but based on the event date :) for now i just want to get all on the screen.. thanks a bunch

Comment: I will, but it actually didn't work.. :( I'm getting an error: private method `include' called for #<Class:0x007fb97a938fb0> Any ideas? thanks

Comment: whops... it's `includes` !! ;)

Comment: oh cool! that fixed it. its not working yet because apperantly rails doesn't see the relation between the two. I have added has_and_belongs_to to both but apparently wasn't enough. But i'm guessing that would be a different question? although it'd be great if you shed that last bit of great knowledge towards this :) thanks anyways!

Comment: `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "events_genres" does not exist
LINE 1: ... ar_association_key_name FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "events_ge...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "genres".*, "t0"."event_id" AS ar_association_key_name FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "events_genres" "t0" ON "genres"."id" = "t0"."genre_id" WHERE "t0"."event_id" IN ('1', '2')`

Comment: It seems rails is "thinking" that in the table genres i should have a field for event_id. But situation is the opposite. In the table events i have a field with genre_id(that contains an array with many ids). any ideas? thanks so much for helping out.

Comment: You need a HABTM association, not a serialized array. You can't do much with the serialized array. The error states it clearly: `relation "events_genres" does not exist` so you have to create it.

Comment: Not sure how to go about fixing this :(

Comment: Please see additional info in original answer.